# I am getting an error when I try to run this simple python script:

Tags: python

```
   temperatures=[10,-20,-289,100]
    for temp > -273 in temperatures:
        c = (temp - 32)*0.5556
        file = open("convert.txt",'a+')
        file.write(c+"\n")
    file.close()
```

> Error:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1,
>   in  NameError: name 'conversion' is not defined

Comment: share your whole code..

Comment: You need to be careful to post the exact code. Ther error says "conversion" but that's not in the script.

Comment: and your indentation is also broken... Fix that by editing your post

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the code that is giving you the error. But I suspect your real problem is here:

```
file.write(c+"\n")
```

`c` is a floating point number and can't be concatenated with a string. You will get the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'. Format your number as a string like this:

```
file.write("{0:.2f}\n".format(c))
```